# Сделать кнопку неактивной и остановить тосты

Tags: android, android-on-click, android-toast

Программа должна выдавать при каждом нажатии на `ImageButton` два `Toast` и проигрывать звук.
На практике если случайно тыкнуть на эту `ImageButton` много раз подряд, получаем серию `Toast`(за все тычки по очереди), разом.

```
public void okv(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    view.setClickable(false);
  Random rand = new Random();
    n = rand.nextInt(5);
    mp.start(); //Это медиаплеер запускается


    if(n == 0)
    {
    Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.a1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

}
    if(n == 1)
    {
        Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.a2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

    }
    if(n == 2)
    {
        Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.a3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

    }
```

Соответственно вопрос - как сделать кнопка действительно неактивной? Почему

```
view.setClickable(false);
```

работает так странно?

Нужно, чтобы нажав её много раз, система регистрировала только первое нажатие, показывала 2 тоста, и лишь потом снова кнопку становилось активной.

Comment: попробуйте  view.setEnabled(false)

Comment: @KirillStoianov без `Thread.sleep` перед  `view.setClickable(true);`  или в вашем случае `view.setEnabled(false)` толку нет вообще. Код исполняется сразу с тостами. Параллельно. Со слипом иногда схватывает первые два нажатия вместо одного. Короче, как то странно работает отключение, может можно как то это более корректно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что если завести еще одну переменну, типа lastTime и установить временной интервал чаще которого нельзя что бы код с тостами отрабатывал. И делать проверку, не слишком ли часто пользователь нажимает на кнопку. В коде это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
long lastTime = 0;
long timeInterval = 1;

public void okv(View view) throws InterruptedException {

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime < timeInterval){
        return;
    }
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    view.setClickable(false);
    Random rand = new Random();
    n = rand.nextInt(5);
    mp.start(); //Это медиаплеер запускается


    if (n == 0) {
        Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.a1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

    }
    if (n == 1) {
        Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.a2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

    }
    if (n == 2) {
        Toast toast = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.a3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
        Toast toast1 = makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.show();
        view.setClickable(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Хотел предложить то же самое, вот только работу со временем забыл, пока вспоминал - вы опередили)

Comment: если `long timeInterval = 1;` то не работает. А вот если от 1000 до 3000 то все отлично. В миллисекундах же.